# Using training data and testing data in a shared task

Tags: machine-learning

I am working on this shared task http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2017/task4/index.php?id=data-and-tools

which is just a twitter sentiment analysis. Since i am pretty new to machine learning, I am not quite sure how to use both training data and testing data.

So the shared task provides two same sets of twitter tweets one without the result (train) and one with the result.

I current understandings of using these kinds of data in machine learning are as follows:

- training set: we are supposed to split this into training and testing portions (90% training and 10% testing maybe?)

But the existing of a separate test data kind of confuses.

Are we supposed to use the result that we got in the test using the 10% portion of the 'training set' and compare that to the actual result 'testing set' ?

Can someone correct my understanding?

Comment: See the answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set); the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_test,_and_validation_sets) could also be useful. Devote some time to grasp the basics of ML instead of jumping directly to "action"...

Comment: Thanks. In the link that I provided, it gives me a training set with NO expected result. Is this normal? According to the link you provided, training set should have the expected label. My link provided a separate testset which has the correct label. I've read the explanations but this somehow differs from what I've read..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When training a machine learning model, you are feeding your algorithm with the dataset called `training set`, which in this stage, you are telling the algorithm what is the ground truth of each sample you put into the algorithm, that way, the algorithm learns from each sample you are feeding to it. the `training set` is usually 80% of the whole dataset, the other 20% of the dataset is the `testing set`, which in this case, you know what is the ground truth of each sample, but you let your algorithm predict what it think the truth is to each sample you let it predict. All those prediction over the `testing set` are based on what the algorithm have learned from the `training set` you fed it before.
After you make all the predictions over your `testing set` you can then check how accurate your model is based on the ground truth in compare to the prediction the model have made.

Comment: The link that I put on my question also provide the test data with correct labels, how does this separate test data differ from the 20% portion of the data which you mentioned as `testing set` ?

Comment: @Dawn17 Apparently, in the link you attached above, they already made the split between `training set` and `testing set`. In every case, in order to know how good you trained your model, all your samples needs to have a correct label which you can check whether or not the model made a good prediction.

Comment: for the `training set`, the correct labels are in order to make the algorithm learn from it, and for the `testing set`, the label are meant in order to check whether the algorithm made a good prediction

Comment: The `training set` provided by the link has empty labels which means I cannot test by splitting that into 80% training data and 20% test data. And that is why they provided us a separate training set with correct labels and that should be used in the testing procedure instead of the 20% portion of the training data. Am I right?

Comment: @Dawn17, from what I just seen, there is a zip file down the page which says `The test data can be found here`, which contains the correct labels of the testing set

Comment: My question is, do we still have to split the training set into 8:2 if they provide separate test data?

Comment: @Dawn17, you can try splitting the `training set` into 80% `training` and 20% `testing` and run your model to see how accurate it is over the 20% of the dataset you put under `testing`. Based on the accuracy rate that you are getting, you can then try to predict all the `testing set` which you say you have no label for. But in general, having data with no correct label makes it unsupervised learning which is based on other algorithms than supervised learning. **Note:** please check all zip files in the link you attached, to see if there are really no labels for the `testing set`

Comment: I understand! It's just weird that some data labeled as test data has no label. But some test data do have labels. So, in general, we only need one training set that has labels and use that to both fit our model and test the accuracy, right?

Comment: @Dawn17, before splitting the dataset into training and testing, there's just a dataset, you decide how you want to split it. But indeed you are correct, you need `training set` to train your model and `testing set` to test your model. Both sets needs to have correct label (in supervised learning)

Comment: I see! It's weird that they have training set and test set separately and one having no labels.. So with the 20% of the testset, is this where we apply our own evaluation metric of our implemented system (F-score, recall, precision, etc.) ??

Comment: @Dawn17, Exactly! the F1-score, precision and recall are meant in order to check how good are the predictions of your model over your **testing set**. If your scores over the testing set are high enough, you can even try predict the unlabeled data and see if your model manage to create good predictions over that set as well (the only problem is that you can't validate the labels for it)

Comment: Thanks for the great response!

Comment: @Dawn17, I'm always happy to help, I'm glad I answered your question. I also recommend following some other examples and tutorials, especially from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com) . You can also see some other people work and see how they approached similar problems